# Liferay not working with MySQL

Tags: mysql, liferay

I am using Liferay 6.1.1 , tomcat 7 and Mysql 5.6 and eclipse.

```
mysql port : localhost 3306
http/1.1 : 8080
```

I followed the instruction given on their wiki
Putting portal-ext.properties into the

```
{liferay-home}\{tomcat}\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes
```

With the following info

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=root
jdbc.default.password=test
```

Created a database with

```
create database lportal character set utf8;
```

The server would run

```
Apr 21, 2013 6:47:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Users\Hnshandroid\Downloads\Liferay vid\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\jre1.6.0_20\win\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;D:\Program Files\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\
Apr 21, 2013 6:47:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 21, 2013 6:47:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 21, 2013 6:47:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 386 ms
Apr 21, 2013 6:47:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 21, 2013 6:47:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
Apr 21, 2013 6:47:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Hnshandroid\Downloads\Liferay vid\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
Loading jar:file:/C:/Users/Hnshandroid/Downloads/Liferay%20vid/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
Loading jar:file:/C:/Users/Hnshandroid/Downloads/Liferay%20vid/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
Loading file:/C:/Users/Hnshandroid/Downloads/Liferay%20vid/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/portal-ide.properties
Loading file:/C:/Users/Hnshandroid/Downloads/Liferay%20vid/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-developer.properties
Loading file:/C:/Users/Hnshandroid/Downloads/Liferay%20vid/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/portal-setup-wizard.properties
Loading file:/C:/Users/Hnshandroid/Downloads/Liferay%20vid/liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.27/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
Apr 21, 2013 6:47:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
18:47:42,768 INFO  [pool-2-thread-1][DialectDetector:71] Determine dialect for MySQL 5
18:47:42,798 INFO  [pool-2-thread-1][DialectDetector:136] Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Starting Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.1.1 CE GA2 (Paton / Build 6101 / July 31, 2012)
18:48:00,025 ERROR [pool-2-thread-1][JDBCExceptionReporter:76] Table 'lportal.lock_' doesn't exist
18:48:00,534 WARN  [pool-2-thread-1][ReleaseLocalServiceImpl:151] Table 'lportal.release_' doesn't exist
18:48:00,535 INFO  [pool-2-thread-1][ReleaseLocalServiceImpl:84] Create tables and populate with default data
```

Till "Create tables and populate with default data"
Then it would hang there. If you press stop, this message will appear

```
Server Liferay v6.1 CE Server (Tomcat 7) at localhost failed to start.
```

Hope someone has a solution for this

Comment: How many **seconds** did you wait before you pressed the `stop` button? :-)

Comment: Oh I manage to solve it. Turns out I am using Mysql 5.6 and not 5.5

Comment: Since you have found the solution, you can answer your own question, and then after a while - accept your answer to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

To populate default data into your lportal db:
Go to Control Panel -> Server administrations -> Database Migration -> add required details. (Please note: use localhost:3306 instead of localhost)

To point liferay to your new db add following lines into your portal-ext.properties file and put this file under the {liferay-home} folder with following info:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=root
jdbc.default.password=test
```

And restart the server. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Goto control panel--->select administrative tools--->select tomcat service--->stop
Again run your program
```

Answer (score 0):

You should download the latest MySQL Connector from this link (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=414247), then unzip the folder, and copy the **.jar** file to **\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib** repository of your Tomcat server.
Restart your Tomcat server, and every thing should run !